# Use of 'not' before subject

Tags: grammar

> "Not is he brave who kills a tiger, but rather, the real brave man is
> the one who controls his anger."

I read this sentence, and it attracted me a lot because of its unique construction, i.e. Not+state verb+ subject..., but the question is if this is grammatical. Although this seems to give much powerful meaning as compared to the following:

> "He is not brave who kills a tiger, but rather, the real brave man is
> the one who controls his anger."

The usual construction: Subject + state verb+ not...

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, and obviously literary. It belongs in the information packaging domain, where it has subject-auxiliary inversion triggered by negative "not".

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical; even beautiful. Because it is not the normal or 'contemporary' way of saying this it forces the reader to carefully consider what is being said; to slow down.

Comment: Where did you "read" that sentence exactly?

Comment: Personally, I think the proper (archaic or inverted) construction here would be: **Not brave is he who kills the tiger**. I have never, ever seen Not is [adjective] in my entire life! It smacks of bad translation. Really bad.

Comment: The more I read this, the more things I see that show me this is not originally in English. It's just a poor translation. "a real brave man", really?? Come on. Not brave is he who kills the tiger as the truly brave man is the one who contains his anger. Much better.

Comment: What about it xeesid, where did you find this?

Comment: It was a research general where I read it. It was translated in English.

Answer (score 6):

This usage is parallelled in modern English:

> Some adverbs (e.g. hardly, little, never, only, scarcely and seldom) have a negative meaning. When we use these at the beginning of the clause, we invert the subject and verb:  ***Hardly had we left** the hotel when it started to pour with rain.*
>
> We also invert the subject and verb after not + a prepositional phrase or not + a clause in front position: ***Not for a moment did I think** I would be offered the job, so I was amazed when I got it.*
> (From https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/negative-adverbs-hardly-seldom-etc )

The following would undoubtedly be grammatical:

- "Hardly is he brave who kills a tiger."
- "Scarcely is he brave who kills a tiger."
- "Never is he brave who kills a tiger."

However, we would never say "Not is he brave who kills a tiger".  I would be tempted to consider the "Not is he brave" variant ungrammatical in modern English.  I do not think that a learner who produced this sentence today could expect their work to be marked correct.

Comment: What about "Not indeed is he..."?

Comment: "Not indeed is he" sounds extremely unnatural, but maybe marginally better than "Not is he".  "Not at all is he" would be an improvement, but the resulting sentence would still be rather awkward.  "Scarcely is he brave", on the other hand, is something I might genuinely write if I were aiming for an elevated, literary style.

Comment: We know all that -- archaic, old-fashioned, unnatural, literary in the extreme, call it what you like. But the OP simply asked if the sentence is grammatical, which it is.

Comment: @BillJ Granted.  And you have already given your view.  I said I would be tempted to regard "Not" on its own in this position as ungrammatical in modern English.  Languages change over time and so does what's considered grammatical.  Plus, native speakers (including linguists) often find that the grammaticality of something is suspect without necessarily being outright wrong (so you see grammarians put a "?" in front of phrases, for example).  It's not always possible to give a straightforward yes/no to whether or not something is grammatical.  But you feel that it is and I respect that.

Comment: On what basis do you say those are undoubtedly grammatical? It seems to me that a minimal requirement is for the adverbs to be pre-positioned to the adjectives: hardly brave is he//scarcely brave is he, and so on with the inversion after those two.

Comment: @Lambie On the basis of my intuition as a native speaker, coupled with my knowledge as someone who has studied linguistics.  I might ask on what basis you think there's a minimal requirement for the adverbs to be pre-positioned.  Do you regard "never was I more stirred" as grammatical ( https://www.lpo.org.uk/rachmaninoff-news/rachmaninoff-contemporaries.html  ) or "never was I more ashamed" ( http://ancientclown.blogspot.com/2006/05/?m=0 )? What about "never am I happy"? ( https://www.wattpad.com/33518862-different-worlds-chapter-5-i-just-want-the-truth/page/2 )

Comment: Of course not: Never was I more stumped. There is no adjective in that one! Never, often, adverbs of frequency. Those would be **perfectly grammatical**.  But here: He who kills a tiger is hardly brave. Clearly, in all three of your sentences, there is an **adverb that modifies an adjective**. So the rule changes. The adverb must accompany the adjective: Hardly brave **is he** who....

Comment: How about "hardly am I flawless" ( https://www.nytimes.com/1988/04/08/opinion/l-fashion-not-the-mini-is-stupid-and-sexist-613888.html )?  Yes, I read your answer with interest and there's a lot we can agree on.  I didn't vote for your answer, but I didn't vote against it, either.

Comment: OK, after thinking about this: If you accept: hardly am I flawless, you have to accept all other forms like that such as: truly am I honest//sincerely am I tolerant//etc. It becomes pretty obvious that an adverb preceding an inversion plus an adjective is not grammatical. Apologies to Maria from Joisey.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about that, because negative adverbs like "never" and "hardly" have a particular pattern of usage. Different grammar applies. One can say "Never would I have guessed it", but I'm not at all sure that one can say "easily would I have guessed it".

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are very archaic, and will be found only in old texts and poetry. Even there, the "Not is he brave" was a poetic form back in the day.

The contemporary version of these would be:

"It's not the one who kills a tiger, who is brave, but rather the one who controls his anger."

Of course without the archaic grammar it doesn't sound nearly as profound.
After all, [quidquid latine dictum sit altum videtur](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-English-translation-of-quidquid-latine-dictum-sit-altum-videtur-and-its-meaning?share=1).

Addressing grammar - English doesn't seem to have any 'facilities' for obsoleting archaic grammar, so everything no matter how archaic is still considered valid, 'legal' grammar because there was a time when they were. So, yes, technically these two are grammatical. On the other hand, they don't even edge into the 'contemporary' territory; they are valid archaic grammar, with no application in modern English beyond deeply archaic stylization.

Comment: OK, but the question is whether it's grammatical.

Comment: Could you provide a source for "Both of these [ . . . ] will be found only in old texts and poetry"? As the OP should, but this answer should stand on its own. Granted, I haven't read much poetry, but I'd expect it to be "Not brave is he", not "Not is he brave". (Any "Not is [subject] [PC]" would do)

Comment: @M.A.R. [Not is * the](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Not+is+*+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), Observe how the plot dwindles. "He is not * who" produces a link too long to paste, you can try it in nGram yourself, the trend is similar.

Comment: [Perhaps most striking...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_end=2019&year_start=1500&content=Not+is+%2A&smoothing=3&corpus=26&direct_url=t2%3B%2CNot%20is%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BNot%20is%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20there%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNot%20is%20in%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: The  percentages are so small, and I was not able to get into the books at all. Ngrams does not cut it for me. You need to provide a grammatical explanation, in my view. Also, I don't know any languages that have "facilities" for obsoleting archaic grammar." (is that even English?).

Comment: @Lambie: In most prescriptive languages the organization responsible for the language can and does declare grammatical forms archaic and incorrect in contemporary usage. English, as a descriptive language lacks such organization. The percentages are small, because that form was never common, and of course it sounds wrong to you because you were born good 300 years too late for it to sound right to you. And sorry, if ngram is not enough for you, you are free to look for other sources yourself. In my opinion it is sufficient to prove that form existed in the language.

Comment: No, ngram is not good enough. And I am a linguist, too. And as such, if the *adverb is clearly related to intensifying an adjective* that would trigger pre-positioning of the adverb in front of the adjective in an inversion where be is present. Also, the co-text clearly shows that the entire sentence is a fool's errand. –

Comment: @Lambie Not sure where you're going with this. I'm definitely not going to start digging through ancient manuscripts in search of a grammatical form which appears roughly once per million phrases, just because in your opinion nGram is not good enough.

Comment: You were asked to show some research and we can't view one book where what you claim is grammatical is shown. That is where this has gone. Unless you show full sentences in written English, this is just a fool's errand. Ngram is just a record keeper, it proves nothing. We don't even know what comes after all those variations you put in there. "Not is he brave" was never a poetic form. Not brave is he, yes.

Comment: @Lambie and then I show you the book and you will declare the author has a bad grammar and it's ungrammatical in that book. It's a fool's errand alright.

Comment: I just knew if: has a bad grammar. Uh-huh.:) Do you know how  I knew? And  you didn't show me any book at all. The plot does indeed "dwindle". Je donnerai ma main à couper.....

Comment: @Lambie: "To be not, or not to be," this is the question...

Comment: Nope, that is the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Bad Translation Revealed**

This sentence: "Not is he brave who kills a tiger, but rather, the real brave man is the one who controls his anger." is not grammatical in English, due to "Not is he brave". The sentence is poor translation from another language.

Inversion in English is used with some regular expressions such as:
Not only: "Not only **did he rush** his speech, he mangled it."
Notice: it's same as the question form: did he rush

Uninverted that would be: "He not only **rushed his speech,** he mangled it."

There are adverbs that also allow for this: "Never have I seen such a thing". for "I have never seen such a thing".

Inversion allows for the subject-verb to be inverted but also an auxiliary is often inserted as one finds in questions: Did he ever sing that day.

Here are some more taken with everyday features taken from a site that explains inversions:

**Wonderful is the way I feel.**
Here are some other examples of inversion a person might say:

Shocked, **I was.**
Tomorrow **will come the decision**.
How amazing **this is.**

[inversion](http://www.literarydevices.com/inversion/)

For this, "Not is he brave who kills a tiger", to be properly inverted, **it has to be**:

1. **Not brave *is he* who kills a tiger.** [subject and verb inverted]

The phrasing "not is he brave" sounds like Spanish or Portuguese: **No es valiente un hombre que mata un tigre** or Não é valente um homem que etc.. You can do that in Spanish and Portuguese but not in English.

2. the real brave man

In colloquial speech, we say: "Oh, he was a real brave man". to mean: "He was a really brave man". In other words, the adverb should be *really* and not real. Otherwise, it would not match a formal level of language as this sentence should do.

In a properly translated poetic-type text as this one purports to be, one would see something like: **for the truly brave man** is the one who

that **but rather** also smacks of translation and is not merited here in English.

3. "controls his anger" sounds overly modern, if the point is to have a beautifully rendered sentence that sounds formally good *contains* is better here.

Rewritten to sound like a proverb that has been well translated (though I have zero idea what language this actually comes from):

"**Not brave is he** who kills a tiger **for the truly brave man** is the one who **contains** his anger."